# Is this considered 2 Factor Authentication?

Tags: vpn, authentication, security, watchguard

Trying to create a 2 Factor Authentication for users to access data remotely.

Here my scenario:

We have a Watchguard to VPN into the network - If we use it's internal DB to store authentication information.

Then use Active Directory credentials to RDP or access files on a server.

Would that count?

Answer (score 5):

No, With two factor you are authenticated by two of three factors (there may be more but these are the three most common).

1. Something you have (RSA key/Smart Card/etc)
2. Something you know (password)
3. Something you are (Fingerprint/biometrics)

Also I can say that a security auditor would probably not be pleased at storing authentication info in any way.